# Sprite not moving in a fixed path for all devices using PathModifier in Andengine

Tags: andengine

I have to move these Sprites (balls) like this in andengine. I am able to do it using path modifier by taking co-ordinates but the main problem is how to make it to work for all resolution tabs? Because whatever co-ordinate I am taking is fixed for the device but not exactly fitting for others. My path is like this

```
final Path path = new Path(12).to(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 440).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 285, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 440)
          .to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 280, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 435).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 275, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 430)
          .to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 270, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 425).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 265, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 420)
          .to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 260, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 415).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 255, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 410)
          .to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 250, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 405).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 250, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 400)
          .to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 250, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 200).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 250, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 200);
```

[image]

help

Comment: Basically RatioResolutionPolicy already doing this stuff for you. So for other devices you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In andengine if you target for one resolution then it will automatically compatible to all other resolution devices.But you have to implement your code in camera width and camera height values format.

So, convert all these hard coded values to  camera width and camera height format.It will work.